# memoization should have worked

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic, computer-science, memoization

without memoization this solution for [Euler Project 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14) works fine! Then with memoization it should work faster... but it stops nearly at `i = 1818` or near. How strange! what's wrong trying hard to understand! can you help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define limit 1000000

int arr[limit];

int fun(long long int i) {
    long long int count = 1;
    long long int num;
    arr[limit];
    num = i;
    while (num > 1) {
        if (arr[num] != NULL) {
            count = count - 1 + arr[num];
            break;
        }
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            num = num / 2;
            count++;
        } else {
            num = 3 * num + 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    arr[i] = count;
    return count;
}

int main() {
    long long int i;
    for (i = 2; i < limit; i++) {
        long long int count = fun(i);
        printf("d %lld c: %lld\n", i, count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Declare `arr[]` as a `static` array, or it will disappear every time you reach the `return` statement. You should also initialize it if you want sensible results.

Comment: Your function `fun` returns an `int`, so why store it in a `long long int`?  There's no advantage to doing so.  If it doesn't fit in an `int`, then the return value will be wrong and it won't matter what you do with it.  Probably you intended the function to return a `long long int`, but you declared it wrong.

Comment: @r3mainer `arr` appears to be global, and hence has static storage.  The instance of `arr[limit];` inside the function is a useless statement that at best does nothing.

Comment: @TomKarzes Ah, you're right.

Comment: `num` can be higher that 10^6. Then `arr[num]` can lead to an undefined behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think the main problem with your code is that the Collatz sequence can give you numbers that are *much* higher than the one you started with before descending to 1. According to [Project Euler 14](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), you're supposed to find the starting number below 1000000 that produces the longest chain before reaching zero. But the Collatz sequence starting at 1819 includes numbers that are larger than one million. As a result, you're attempting to access elements of `arr[]` that are way out of bounds.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, the statement `arr[limit];` in your `fun()` function does nothing useful. If you had enabled warnings in your compiler, it probably would have flagged this, as well as the statement `if(arr[num]!=NULL)`, which compares a `void*` pointer with an integer.

If you replace the first statement of your `while()` block with `if (num < limit && arr[num]!=NULL)`, then you should at least avoid the segmentation fault.

Your `main()` function needs to be rewritten to find the starting number that produces the longest chain, instead of just printing out a million lines of data.

If you like, you could try running this instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIMIT 1000000

int arr[LIMIT] = { 0 };

long fun(long i) {
    long count = 1;
    long num;
    num = i;
    while (num > 1) {
        if (num < LIMIT && arr[num] != 0) {
            count = count - 1 + arr[num];
            break;
        }
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            num = num / 2;
            count++;
        }
        else {
            num = 3 * num + 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    arr[i] = count;
    return count;
}

int main(){
    long i, longest=0, maxstart;
    for (i=2; i<LIMIT; i++) {
        long count = fun(i);
        if (count > longest) {
            longest = count;
            maxstart = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld\n",maxstart);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem statement even points this out - ***NOTE**: Once the chain starts the terms are allowed to go above one million.*

Comment: @r3mainer Oh my God! you explained it so nicely that is splendid! Now the code running really very fast...! Though it was not my complete solution for the Eu14 problem... but I messed up everything and edited everything just to get something as output with Memoization that I learnt yesterday...     Thank you so so much..for taking time and pointing out my problems! I'm really grateful.